# How to use a named delegate to a Comparison for List.Sort()?

Tags: c#, delegates

In my app, I have several comparison methods.  I would like the user to be able to select the sorting method to use.  Ideally, I would like to set a delegate and it is updated based on the user's selection.  This way, I can keep the code generic using List.Sort(delegate).

This is my first time attempting to use C# delegates and I'm running into syntax errors.  Here is what I have so far:

The delegate:

```
private delegate int SortVideos(VideoData x, VideoData y);
private SortVideos sortVideos;
```

In the class constructor:

```
sortVideos = Sorting.VideoPerformanceDescending;
```

The comparison method in the public static Sorting class (which works when I call it directly):

```
public static int VideoPerformanceDescending(VideoData x, VideoData y)
{
    *code statements*
    *return -1, 0, or 1*
}
```

Failed syntax that complains of "some invalid arguments":

```
videos.Sort(sortVideos);
```

Ultimately, I would like to change "sortVideos" to point to the method of choice.  "videos" is a list of type VideoData. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `videos`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `List<T>` accepts a delegate of type `Comparison<T>` so you cannot define your own delegate, you just need to reuse the delegate `Comparison<T>`.

```
private static Comparison<VideoData> sortVideos;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    sortVideos = VideoPerformanceDescending;

    var videos = new List<VideoData>();

    videos.Sort(sortVideos);
}
```

Expanding the answer to also contemplate the user selection part, you could store the available options in a dictionary and then in the UI allow the user to select the sort algorithm by selecting the key to the dictionary.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Comparison<VideoData>> sortAlgorithms;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var videos = new List<VideoData>();

    var sortAlgorithms = new Dictionary<string, Comparison<VideoData>>();

    sortAlgorithms.Add("PerformanceAscending", VideoPerformanceAscending);
    sortAlgorithms.Add("PerformanceDescending", VideoPerformanceDescending);

    var userSort = sortAlgorithms[GetUserSortAlgorithmKey()];

    videos.Sort(userSort);
}

private static string GetUserSortAlgorithmKey()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static int VideoPerformanceDescending(VideoData x, VideoData y)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static int VideoPerformanceAscending(VideoData x, VideoData y)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Sort` takes a `Comparison<T>` delegate type, not your `SortVideos` delegate type.

You should not be creating a delegate type at all.
Instead, just write

```
videos.Sort(SomeMethod);
```